# Create Multiple Keys for ASP.NET IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, primary-key

I am creating a multi-tenant application (MVC) and am using Identity.  In my `IdentityUser` class, I added a property for the tenant identifier:

```
public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
```

By default, the Id property is the key (translates to the Id column in the database).  I want to add TenantId to the primary keys so that there can be multiple users with the same username, but will have different TenantId's.  Can someone explain how to do this in the model class?  My example class below:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found multiple solutions, but ultimately, I ended up using this poster's design:

https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy